# How to Set CSSID in jdbc db2 using java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

My current task is to migrate a remote database to a localhost database. Everything seems fine up to now. The problem is when I'm checking whether the data are the same, data in my localhost weren't copied correctly. Japanese, Chinese and Arabic Characters were all question marks with boxes. I've searched the net and I've come to understand that it has something to do with the encoding scheme. I've checked the syntax, but none of them seem to work for me. 
Can you provide me how to do it using JAVA?

NOTE: I seem to have a problem altering the database, (i think i don't have the permission ) so i would like to know if setting cssid in the tablespace is applicable.

Comment: What database flavors are you copying from and to?

Comment: Are you migrating the data using your java app?

Answer (score 0):

When I once had trouble with encodings in DBs it was of a missing param in the commandline of my app:

```
java ... -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could come from the [database codeset](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/t0004617.html) which permits to define the type of characters you are entering. However, it cannot be canged once the database was created.

Also, a normal column could not support graphic characters. Probably, you need to use a column that support graphic characters like: [Graphic, vargraphic or dbclob](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008471.html)